# How to make views slideshow, shows more items per page than one

Tags: 7, views

I made a slideshow using views slideshow in drupal 7 to show bunch of logos, but it only shows one item per page, what I want is to show for example 6 logos per page when the visitor hit next, it slides to next 6 items and etc.. I checked views slideshow field setting, but couldnt find anywhere that I can set how many items to show per page.

thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Views Slideshow 7.x-3.0, you can find this option by selecting slideshow as your format and then clicking on settings. From there, you need to find the Action section and check "View Action Advanced Options", there you can choose how many items to display.

Comment: The "Items per slide" option has been removed from Views Slideshow 7.x-3.1.

Comment: in drupal 8 with slideshow module it is possible to show multiple items in option described above but is there a setting to show 4 items and slide only by one? Lets say i have 10 items and i want to show 4 at the beginning and slide by 1 item (node). If we show 4 items per slide it will slide by 4 items... that is a problem for me. could use any help.

Answer (score 4):

From your explanation, you would require a module called [jCarousal](http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel). It has built-in views support too. You can configure its settings change the number of items to show per page.

Comment: thanks, I actually found an option in slideshow itself which allows me to do this.

Comment: Where did you find that option? I know where it is in views slideshow 2.x, but I can't find it in 3.x